# Laravel application trying to authenticate user using another database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two applications both developed in Laravel.I have logged into the first application and doing coding. But when I try to log into the second application it gives an error of the `missing 'users' table`(the table in the second database I am trying to log into now which is not in the first logged in an application).

Seems like the second application is trying to authenticate the user using the first database which is not correct

Can anyone assist me with this

Comment: Without relevant code no one can assist. believe me there is no wizard online right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Laroja as i get you want to authenticate with another application which have separate database then you have to define two database auth and try to build the logic if connect to first application then it uses the first database and if you want to connect with another application it will connect to other database.

Please have a sapmle code for connect two databse

```
 'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'  => 'qmops_live_server',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => '',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        # Secondary database connection
        'mysql2' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database'  => 'XXX',
            'username'  => 'XXX',
            'password'  => 'QXXXX',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

please use the above code in app/config/database.php     hope my solution will help you Thanks.